# no types were parsed that could be bound when trying to bind Zendesk IOS framework

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind the frameworks ZendeskSDK.framework, ZendeskProviderSDK.framework and ZendeskCoreSDK.framework.

The Github link for the [framework](https://www.github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_ios.)

When I run bind command using an objective sharpie for each of the frameworks above, I always get the message "no types were parsed that could be bound". All the above frameworks contain some .h files.

I am using the below command to bind being on the parent folder that contains these frameworks.

> sharpie bind -framework ZendeskProviderSDK.framework
>
> sharpie bind -framework ZendeskSDK.framework
>
> sharpie bind -framework ZendeskCoreSDK.framework

Could you help me with the above issue?

I am trying to bind each of the above frameworks individually into separateAPIDefinition.cs and StructAndenums.cs file. Can we bind 3 frameworks together into one APIDefinition.cs and StructAndenums.cs file?

Comment: Hey ! Could you make it work?